# How to set redirect_uri using QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow and QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler

Tags: c++, qt, oauth-2.0

For OAuth 2.0 using QT's networkauth and the new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow object, how can I set the redirect_uri?  My code is below.  It results in the following authenticate url being sent:

QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::buildAuthenticateUrl: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=123-abc.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:65535/cb&response_type=code&scope=email&state=iEIYn5sN

The setting of redirect_uri to "http://localhost", results in an Error 400 redirect_uri_mismatch from google which is obviously expecting the actual redirect hostname to be provided.

```
GoogleGateway::GoogleGateway() {

auto google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow;
google->setScope("email");

this->connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

QString val;
QFile file;
file.setFileName("/home/me/client_secret.json");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
val = file.readAll();
file.close();

QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
QJsonObject object = document.object();
const auto settingsObject = object["web"].toObject();
const QUrl authUri(settingsObject["auth_uri"].toString());
const auto clientId = settingsObject["client_id"].toString();
const QUrl tokenUri(settingsObject["token_uri"].toString());
const auto clientSecret(settingsObject["client_secret"].toString());
const auto redirectUris = settingsObject["redirect_uris"].toArray();
const QUrl redirectUri(redirectUris[0].toString());
const auto port = static_cast<quint16>(redirectUri.port());

google->setAuthorizationUrl(authUri);
google->setClientIdentifier(clientId);
google->setAccessTokenUrl(tokenUri);
google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(clientSecret);

auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(port, this);
google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);

google->grant();
}
```

To set the redirect_uri, I've tried replacing:

```
auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(port, this);
```

with

```
QHostAddress hostaddress = QHostAddress(quint32(1233...));
auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(hostaddress, port, this);
```

with no change in the result.

Have also tried inserting:

```
replyHandler->setProperty("redirect_uri", "http://abc.xyz.com:65535/cb");
```

also with no change in the result.

In Qt/5.8/Src/qtnetworkauth/src/oauth/qoauthhttpserverreplyhandler.cpp, we see that the callback address looks suspiciously hard-coded:

```
QString QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::callback() const
{
    Q_D(const QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler);

    Q_ASSERT(d->httpServer.isListening());
    const QUrl url(QString::fromLatin1("http://localhost:%1/cb").arg(d->httpServer.serverPort()));
    return url.toString(QUrl::EncodeDelimiters);
}
```

This callback() is in turn used in Qt/5.8/Src/qtnetworkauth/src/oauth/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.cpp to set the redirectUri value:

```
QUrl QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::buildAuthenticateUrl(const QVariantMap &parameters)
{
    Q_D(QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow);
    using Key = QAbstractOAuth2Private::OAuth2KeyString;

    if (d->state.isEmpty())
        setState(QAbstractOAuth2Private::generateRandomState());
    Q_ASSERT(!d->state.isEmpty());
    const QString state = d->state;

    QVariantMap p(parameters);
    QUrl url(d->authorizationUrl);
    p.insert(Key::responseType, responseType());
    p.insert(Key::clientIdentifier, d->clientCredentials.first);
    p.insert(Key::redirectUri, callback());
    p.insert(Key::scope, d->scope);
    p.insert(Key::state, state);
    if (d->modifyParametersFunction)
        d->modifyParametersFunction(Stage::RequestingAuthorization, &p);
    url.setQuery(d->createQuery(p));
    connect(d->replyHandler.data(), &QAbstractOAuthReplyHandler::callbackReceived, this,
            &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizationCallbackReceived, Qt::UniqueConnection);
    setStatus(QAbstractOAuth::Status::NotAuthenticated);
    qDebug("QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::buildAuthenticateUrl: %s", qPrintable(url.toString()));
    return url;
}
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: For anyone similarly confused the resolution is here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59653

Comment: Apparently this is not detected as a bug! but this is certainly a poor implementation of OAuth2 :\

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this by subclassing `MyOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler` and overriding the definition of `callback()` to return the URI I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt 5.15, the redirect_uri could be change form `QAbstractOAuth::modifyParametersFunction`

```cpp
m_google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(m_manager,this);
// set other parameters...
m_google->setModifyParametersFunction(buildModifyParametersFunction());

// return ModifyParametersFunction()
QAbstractOAuth::ModifyParametersFunction GoogleOAuth2Wrapper::buildModifyParametersFunction()
{
    const QUrl clientIdentifier = m_google->clientIdentifier();
    const QUrl clientIdentifierSharedKey = m_google->clientIdentifierSharedKey();
    return [clientIdentifier,clientIdentifierSharedKey]
            (QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QVariantMap *parameters){
        if(stage == QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAuthorization){
            parameters->insert("redirect_uri","https://127.0.0.1:8080/cb"); /*change redirect uri*/
        }
    };
}
```

`QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow` class use `QUrl buildAuthenticateUrl(const QVariantMap &parameters)` method to send browser for access token,here's source:

```cpp
QUrl QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::buildAuthenticateUrl(const QVariantMap &parameters)
{
    Q_D(QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow);
    using Key = QAbstractOAuth2Private::OAuth2KeyString;
    if (d->state.isEmpty())
        setState(QAbstractOAuth2Private::generateRandomState());
    Q_ASSERT(!d->state.isEmpty());
    const QString state = d->state;
    QVariantMap p(parameters);
    QUrl url(d->authorizationUrl);
    p.insert(Key::responseType, responseType());
    p.insert(Key::clientIdentifier, d->clientIdentifier);
    p.insert(Key::redirectUri, callback());
    p.insert(Key::scope, d->scope);
    p.insert(Key::state, state);
    if (d->modifyParametersFunction) /** Here's what we take part **/
        d->modifyParametersFunction(Stage::RequestingAuthorization, &p);
    url.setQuery(d->createQuery(p));
    connect(d->replyHandler.data(), &QAbstractOAuthReplyHandler::callbackReceived, this,
            &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizationCallbackReceived, Qt::UniqueConnection);
    setStatus(QAbstractOAuth::Status::NotAuthenticated);
    qCDebug(d->loggingCategory, "Generated URL: %s", qPrintable(url.toString()));
    return url;
}
```

I hope that is helpful.

### Reference

[QAbstractOAuth::modifyParametersFunction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractoauth.html#modifyParametersFunction)

[QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::buildAuthenticateUrl source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtnetworkauth/src/oauth/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.cpp.html#_ZN28QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow20buildAuthenticateUrlERK4QMapI7QString8QVariantE)

Answer (score 0):

Using Qt 5.15, having your redirect URI overridden is no longer a problem, but there are two others that you might be running into:

- If you use the first URL provided in Google's credential JSON, your app might not hearing back from the user's browser at the end of authorization flow. Instead, just use http://127.0.0.1:1234/ which is reliably the user's machine.
- Depending on your luck, the login code returned by Google is URL-encoded and it may contain characters that need to be URL-decoded before requesting a login token from Google itself. This is something that I'd expect Qt to take care of for you, but instead you have to inject a parameter modifier.

Here is the key block, taken from our post on [authenticating a Qt app with Google SSO](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/):

```
this->google->setModifyParametersFunction([](QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QVariantMap* parameters) {
   // Percent-decode the "code" parameter so Google can match it
   if (stage == QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAccessToken) {
      QByteArray code = parameters->value("code").toByteArray();
      (*parameters)["code"] = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(code);
   }
});
```