# Login and getting file from Google Drive or Dropbox by using Qt/QML in Android and iOS

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, qt5, dropbox-api

I am developing app for Android and iOS by using QML/Qt 5.9.1. We want to login the Google Drive and download and upload some file. Of course, we must can select file from my App. Hence, I am trying to use the 3rd part library.
Hence, my first thing is to find the sample code for login by using Qt.
I follow the below line with two article.

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/

[How to set redirect_uri using QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow and QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595210/how-to-set-redirect-uri-using-qoauth2authorizationcodeflow-and-qoauthhttpserverr)

I can get login page from browser when I process the QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow part in my Qt code. I think it want to use REST to get message from Google's api as below link.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

I develop app for mobile phone but I must login Google Drive by using the "browser". I think it is weird. By the way, in the above link, there no other code for getting file list from Google Drive. I got stuck here.

Hence, I trying to study using the native code to implement this by using mobile api without web's api. The idea is to implement the whole thing in native code.

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/

And using JNI or other method to passing message from the native code to Qt. But it seem pretty complex and I find I can't run the Google's sample code successfully in my red-mi note 4. I can't login Google Drive and I alway in the select account page on the sample code as below link.

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/43

I am study how to use Dropbox now. I can get workable sample code from below link.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60400

I can login, upload, download and remove from the sample code. But the problem is it still using "browser" to login account. And I must copy the pin code and paste the pin code to my app for finished the OAuth. It is not friendly and it is hard to copy the pin code from my mobile phone. By the way, I must paste the pin code for login every time when I open the app.

Does it possible to login in my app without the "browser" by using REST?
Does it possible not re-paste the pin code every time?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it possible to login in my app without the "browser" by using REST?

No, Dropbox API apps must be authorized by the user via the OAuth app authorization flow, which requires a browser for the authorization step.

> Does it possible not re-paste the pin code every time?

Yes, once you have an access token for a user, you can store and re-use it for future API calls for that user without further manual user intervention.

Further, note that you can use a redirect URI to streamline the app authorization flow so that the user doesn't need to manually copy and paste a code. You can find more information on how this works in the documentation:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization

Comment: Why can it login in their app without using the browser? This is the video I capture from the other app: [DropBox login example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4xpZcFHmZ4edDBuTmR2aGhvSkU/view?usp=sharing) about the question 1. Do I misunderstand something? And I will study how to store and re-use it for the API call about the question 2.

Comment: This is the video I capture from my Qt-Dropbox project in my phone [Qt_Dropbox_login](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4xpZcFHmZ4eMGNKMWZsUlJCNWc/view?usp=sharing). I must login from the browser and past the pin code to my app.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. That video does show the user signing in and authorizing the app, via a browser in an embedded web view.

Comment: Oops, using embedded web view. That let me felt confused several weeks... .I will study how to use it in Qt. The grant event of Qt always open my browser for login... .But do you know why they login Dropbox without pin code? I thought the pin code is the one part  of the OAuth before.

Comment: The video actually shows an older SDK that uses an older version of OAuth that doesn't use an authorization code. When implementing your app now, you should follow the documentation linked in my answer above.