# How to create a login page using Qt oauth?

Tags: c++, qt, oauth

I've been looking around on the web on how to create an authentication page when my Qt desktop app opens. I already built the app; that is pretty small and only composed of a MainWindow called from main.cpp.

Now I'd like to add an authentication page when the user opens the app. I created a Google API (following the instruction from this link: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/); but it is really incomplete. And looking on the web, I wasn't able to find a single link that gives a working example where:
- The user runs the app and gets asked for his username and password;
- And if it doesn't exist yet, he can create one.

All I've found is incomplete piece of code like the link I shared above; or tutorial that shows how to create a login page with hard-coded passwords and usernames (this is not what I want, I want people to be able to add themselves dynamically based of the Google API).

So please, if someone has a little piece of code where the user gets asked for their username and password, with the code managing the request to the API, that would be great!

---

**EDIT: Adding my code**

I'm adding the code of my class GoogleGateway (inspired from what I found here: [How to set redirect_uri using QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow and QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595210/how-to-set-redirect-uri-using-qoauth2authorizationcodeflow-and-qoauthhttpserverr))

**GoogleGateway.h:**

```
#ifndef GOOGLEGATEWAY_H
#define GOOGLEGATEWAY_H

#include <QObject>

class GoogleGateway : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GoogleGateway();
};

#endif // GOOGLEGATEWAY_H
```

**GoogleGateway.cpp:**

```
#include "googlegateway.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow>
#include <QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler>
#include <QDesktopServices>

GoogleGateway::GoogleGateway() :
    QObject(){

auto google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow;
google->setScope("email");

this->connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

QString val;
QFile file;
file.setFileName("/.../auth.json");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
val = file.readAll();
file.close();

QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
QJsonObject object = document.object();
const auto settingsObject = object["web"].toObject();
const QUrl authUri(settingsObject["auth_uri"].toString());
const auto clientId = settingsObject["client_id"].toString();
const QUrl tokenUri(settingsObject["token_uri"].toString());
const auto clientSecret(settingsObject["client_secret"].toString());
const auto redirectUris = settingsObject["redirect_uris"].toArray();
const QUrl redirectUri(redirectUris[0].toString());
const auto port = static_cast<quint16>(redirectUri.port());

google->setAuthorizationUrl(authUri);
google->setClientIdentifier(clientId);
google->setAccessTokenUrl(tokenUri);
google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(clientSecret);

auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(port, this);
google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);

google->grant();

}
```

Now, what do I need to do in my MainWindow.cpp to prompt a login page that will use the class GoogleGateway? Does the class GoogleGateway look good as it is? Or do I need to modify something?

Also, I created an instance of the class GoogleGateway in my MainWindow constructor. And When I run the code, it opens a web tab in my Chrome but throws the Error 400 saying "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch". What does that mean?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Example in Qt blog is actually complete... And works. Just connect to QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted() and show your MainWindow. If you have problems with your code, show it. Nobody can know why something don't work for you...

Comment: I don't know what to show as far as the code, as I don't see where and how to put the pieces of code of the Qt blog... To me, it is unclear what to do with the pieces of code the blogger presented on his blog. So that was what I was asking; what is the actual complete code that integrates the pieces of code on the blog? And you can't say the code is complete, I don't see any class definition not method integrating the code. And it might be obvious for some people what to do with it; but for me it isn't.

Comment: @Xplatforms: I added the code I have in my initial post. Please, if you could give me your opinion/advise about what is missing to accomplish what I intend; I would be grateful for that. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the article from Qt blog is almost complete. You just need to connect `granted` signal and make needed requests after that.

Note about /cb path in redirect_uri in Qt blog is not valid anymore(article came about a year ago).

> NOTE: The path “/cb” is mandatory in the current
>   QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler implementation.

So if you see access error from google after running your code, just copy-paste redirect_uri from there into GoogleConsole Authorized redirect URIs of your configured client. **http://localhost:8080/** <- don't forget slash at the end

[image]

*P.S.: Don't forget to dowload json file with credentials from console again.*

Also if you want to call any Google APIs after authorization, you need to enable them in GoogleConsole for your project. To test the code just enable `Google+ API`

[image]

That's it. Here is the complete and working code. (Tested on Linux and Qt 5.10, Don't have Windows at the moment, can't test it there)

**googlegateway.h**

```
#ifndef GOOGLEGATEWAY_H
#define GOOGLEGATEWAY_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class GoogleGateway : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GoogleGateway(QObject *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow * google;
};

#endif // GOOGLEGATEWAY_H
```

**googlegateway.cpp**

```
#include "googlegateway.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler>
#include <QDesktopServices>


GoogleGateway::GoogleGateway(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(this);
    this->google->setScope("email");

    connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

    QByteArray val;
    QFile file;
    file.setFileName(QDir::toNativeSeparators("/full/path/client_secret_XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com.json"));
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        val = file.readAll();
        file.close();
    }


    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val);
    QJsonObject object = document.object();
    const auto settingsObject = object["web"].toObject();
    const QUrl authUri(settingsObject["auth_uri"].toString());
    const auto clientId = settingsObject["client_id"].toString();
    const QUrl tokenUri(settingsObject["token_uri"].toString());
    const auto clientSecret(settingsObject["client_secret"].toString());

    const auto redirectUris = settingsObject["redirect_uris"].toArray();
    const QUrl redirectUri(redirectUris[0].toString());
    const auto port = static_cast<quint16>(redirectUri.port());

    this->google->setAuthorizationUrl(authUri);
    this->google->setClientIdentifier(clientId);
    this->google->setAccessTokenUrl(tokenUri);
    this->google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(clientSecret);

    auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(port, this);
    this->google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
    this->google->grant();

    connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=](){
        qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << __LINE__ << "Access Granted!";
        auto reply = this->google->get(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"));
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply](){
            qDebug() << "REQUEST FINISHED. Error? " << (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError);
            qDebug() << reply->readAll();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for you detailed answer. I am still having trouble to implement this. My problem is the redirect Uri, could you please take a look at my post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296641/unable-to-implement-google-sign-in-using-qoauth2authorizationcodeflow

Comment: We have published a post discussing some of these problems in https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to set Redirect URI in google console to `http://127.0.0.1:port_no/` instead of `http://localhost:port_no/` for all localhost.

Remember to put the trailing '/' in the Redirect URI.

Rest of the code

```
this->google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(this);
        this->google->setScope("email");

        connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

        this->google->setAuthorizationUrl(QUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"));
        this->google->setClientIdentifier(MY_CLIENT_ID);
        this->google->setAccessTokenUrl(QUrl("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"));
        this->google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(MYTOKEN);

// In my case, I have hardcoded 8080 to test
        auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(8080, this);
        this->google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
        this->google->grant();

        qDebug() << "Access";

        connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=](){
            qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << __LINE__ << "Access Granted!";

            auto reply = this->google->get(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"));
            connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply](){
                qDebug() << "REQUEST FINISHED. Error? " << (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError);
                qDebug() << reply->readAll();
            });
        });
```