# Google Sign-in Using Firebase and Qt

Tags: android, c++, firebase, qt

I'm trying to implement `Google Sign-in` option for my android app using `Qt` and `Firebase Google Authentication` by using [Connecting your Qt application with Google Services using OAuth 2.0](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0) and [Authenticate Using Google Sign-In and C++](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/google-signin).

After clicking on a push button in my app the consent page (*if I didn't misname it*) loads correctly which allows the user to choose his/her desired google account but after that nothing happens. I don't know whether the problem is with my `redirected URI` or something else. 
I have enabled `Google Sign-in Option` in my `Firebase Console` and followed the suggested steps in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453550/how-to-create-a-login-page-using-qt-oauth). What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
this->google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(this);
this->google->setScope("email");

connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

QByteArray val;
QFile file;
file.setFileName(QDir::toNativeSeparators(":/client_secret.json"));
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    val = file.readAll();
    file.close();
}


QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val);
QJsonObject object = document.object();
const auto settingsObject = object["web"].toObject();
const QUrl authUri(settingsObject["auth_uri"].toString());
const auto clientId = settingsObject["client_id"].toString();
const QUrl tokenUri(settingsObject["token_uri"].toString());
const auto clientSecret(settingsObject["client_secret"].toString());

//const auto redirectUris = settingsObject["redirect_uris"].toArray();
const QUrl redirectUri("https://MYAPP.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler");
const auto port = static_cast<quint16>(redirectUri.port());

this->google->setAuthorizationUrl(authUri);
this->google->setClientIdentifier(clientId);
this->google->setAccessTokenUrl(tokenUri);
this->google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(clientSecret);


auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(port, this);
replyHandler->setProperty("redirect_uri", "https://MYAPP.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler");
this->google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
this->google->grant();


connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=](){

    firebase::auth::Auth* auth = firebase::auth::Auth::GetAuth(_app);

    firebase::auth::Credential credential = firebase::auth::GoogleAuthProvider::GetCredential(google->token().toUtf8(),nullptr);
    firebase::Future<firebase::auth::User*> result = auth->SignInWithCredential(credential);
    result.OnCompletion([&](const firebase::Future<firebase::auth::User*>& result)
    {
        if  (result.error()==0)
        {
            qDebug() << "good to go";
        }
        else
        {   
            qDebug() << result.error_message();
        }
    }
    );
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't use Firebase, but we noticed that the only way to get a response from the OAuth flow is by using http://127.0.0.1:1234/ as the redirect URL. We wrote about [authenticating with Google SSO and Qt](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/) in our blog, including a discussion of this aspect, and code samples that build on the Qt-provided examples.

Comment: Dear Pablo, I truly appreciate your answer. Unfortunately I am not working on this project anymore as a long time has passed, and I cannot verify whether this solution solves the problem. If I was able to implement your suggestion and test it out anytime soon, I will definitely share the results here. Nevertheless, I will upvote your answer for pointing out the problem with OAuth. Thanks again~!

Comment: No worries, I wrote the linked post, and I just wanted to share it in case it helps others. Thanks for the upvote!