# QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow accessing Spotify

Tags: qt, spotify

I am trying to make [this](https://github.com/adminundcode/qt-spotify-webapi) project to work.

I changed `mainwindow.cpp:22` to use my `Client Id`, and `mainwindow.cpp:23` to use my `Client Secret`, that I registered for my app at Spotify.

But, it does not matter which Redirect URI I set for my app registration, at Spotify, this example uses `redirect_uri=http://localhost/:8080` in the URL. I tried to edit it to `redirect_uri=https://localhost/:8080`, as I (think I) read somewhere, but with no results: the browser reports `INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI`.

I also tried to insert `replyHandler->setProperty("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:8080/");` after line 19.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595210/how-to-set-redirect-uri-using-qoauth2authorizationcodeflow-and-qoauthhttpserverr), [this](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/) and [this](https://adminundcode.de/using-spotify-webapi-with-qt/), but I just can't get it to work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update** I managed to make the login web page to appear, but I had to clear (all) the browser's cache. However, after typing my email and password, it seems it does not actually access Spotify, as nothing happens in the app. I wonder if my account at Spotify must be premium

Comment: **Updating** 

I managed to make the login web page to appear, but I had to clear (all) the browser's cache. 

However, after typing my email and password, it seems it does not actually access Spotify, as nothing happens in the app.

I wonder if my account at Spotify must be premium.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: it was a misconfiguration between what I registered at Spotify, and what I was using in the app.